# numpy.core._exceptions._ArrayMemoryError: Unable to allocate 341. KiB for an array

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, out-of-memory

I have a python web socket server which is continuously running. There is a pandas dataframe stored in Memory, and on receiving certain updates the in-memory pandas dataframe needs to be updated as well. Whenever a new record is received, It is appended to the dataframe and post update I am using `pandas.reset_index()` to update the data.

```py
self._pos_data.loc[len(self._pos_data)] =[info['Username'],info['Symbol'],int(id),_dateConvert,_timeOfTrade,_value]
self._pos_data=self._pos_data.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Note that `info['Username']`, `info['Symbol']`, `int(id)`, `_dateConvert`, `_timeOfTrade`,  `_value` are variables.
I am getting the following error on `reset_index()` after few hours of running the script.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen client-server>", line 229, in onMessage
  File "C:\\Users\\centraadmin\\Desktop\\Centra\\RELEASE201123\\CentraEngine\\centra\\lib\\site-packages\\pandas\\core\\frame.py", line 6165, in reset_index
    new_obj = self.copy(deep=None)
  File "C:\\Users\\centraadmin\\Desktop\\Centra\\RELEASE201123\\CentraEngine\\centra\\lib\\site-packages\\pandas\\core\\generic.py", line 6685, in copy
    data = self._mgr.copy(deep=deep)
  File "C:\\Users\\centraadmin\\Desktop\\Centra\\RELEASE201123\\CentraEngine\\centra\\lib\\site-packages\\pandas\\core\\internals\\managers.py", line 576, in copy
    res = self.apply("copy", deep=deep)
  File "C:\\Users\\centraadmin\\Desktop\\Centra\\RELEASE201123\\CentraEngine\\centra\\lib\\site-packages\\pandas\\core\\internals\\managers.py", line 354, in apply
    applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
  File "C:\\Users\\centraadmin\\Desktop\\Centra\\RELEASE201123\\CentraEngine\\centra\\lib\\site-packages\\pandas\\core\\internals\\blocks.py", line 645, in copy
    values = values.copy()
numpy.core._exceptions._ArrayMemoryError: Unable to allocate 341. KiB for an array with shape (1, 43613) and data type object
```

How do I resolve this? I cannot think of an alternative to reset_index() as not resetting the index throws problem while using the dataframe for other operations.